# API Hooking, unexpected handle found on TerminateProcess function

Tags: .net, vb.net, hook, api-hook, deviare

### PROBLEM

I've hooked the [**TerminateProcess**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) calls to identify the process which is being terminated, but I'm getting an unexpected handle from `TerminateProcess` that does not match with the real process handle that I try to intercept.

I'm using **Deviare** library but I think this issue could be solved just knowing how the `TerminateProcess` function works and what I need to do to perform a proper handle comparison.

### QUESTION:

If I know the handle of a process which I want to identify its termination, how I could identify that handle from `hProcess` param of `TerminateProcess` function?

### CODE:

Note the part where I try to compare the handles:

```
If Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault.Handle = hProcessValue Then ...
```

It will never be the same handles (I also tried with `MainWindowHandle` and the **Process ID** `ID`)

So, the value of `hProcess` parameter is very unknown for me.

```
Imports Nektra.Deviare2

Public NotInheritable Class Form1

Public WithEvents SpyMgr As NktSpyMgr
Public Hook As NktHook

ReadOnly libName As String = "kernel32.dll"
ReadOnly funcName As String = "TerminateProcess"
ReadOnly hookFlags As eNktHookFlags = eNktHookFlags.flgOnlyPreCall

' Processes to attach the hook.
ReadOnly processesToAttach As IEnumerable(Of Process) =
    Process.GetProcessesByName("taskmgr")

Private Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Load

    If Me.processesToAttach.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Any process found.")

    Else
        Me.SpyMgr = New NktSpyMgr()
        Me.SpyMgr.Initialize()

        Me.Hook = SpyMgr.CreateHook(String.Format("{0}!{1}", libName, funcName), hookFlags)
        Me.Hook.Hook(sync:=True)

        For Each proc As Process In processesToAttach
            Debug.WriteLine("Attaching to: " & proc.ProcessName)
            Me.Hook.Attach(procOrId:=proc.Id, sync:=True)
        Next proc

    End If

End Sub

<MTAThread>
Private Sub OnTerminateProcess_Called(ByVal hook As NktHook,
                                      ByVal proc As NktProcess,
                                      ByVal callInfo As NktHookCallInfo) Handles SpyMgr.OnFunctionCalled

    ' Function params.
    Dim hProcessParam As NktParam = DirectCast(callInfo.Params(0), NktParam)
    Dim uExitCodeParam As NktParam = DirectCast(callInfo.Params(1), NktParam)

    ' Param values.
    Dim hProcessValue As IntPtr = New IntPtr(CInt(hProcessParam.Value))
    Dim uExitCodeValue As UInteger = CUInt(uExitCodeParam.Value)

    ' Debuf info.
    Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("hProcess : '{0}'", hProcessValue))
    Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("uExitCode: '{0}'", uExitCodeValue))

    ' Handle Comparison
    If Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault.Handle = hProcessValue Then

        ' Skip precall to avoid process termination.
        If callInfo.IsPreCall Then
            callInfo.Result.Value = 1
            callInfo.SkipCall()
        End If

    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

### RESEARCH:

I've been reading the MSDN doc of [**TerminateProcess**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Note the parts where it says:

> The handle must have the PROCESS_TERMINATE access right

I'm not sure whether I'm missed something to compare the handles.

Also I've been reading here but I didn't take any in clear:

[Hooking TerminateProcess & Getting Info From The Handle It Supplies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117477/hooking-terminateprocess-getting-info-from-the-handle-it-supplies)

I also designed this Enum if it could be necessary to perform a good handle comparison:

```
    Public Enum ProcessAccessFlags As UInteger
       All = &H1F0FFF
       Terminate = &H1
       CreateThread = &H2
       VirtualMemoryOperation = &H8
       VirtualMemoryRead = &H10
       VirtualMemoryWrite = &H20
       DuplicateHandle = &H40
       CreateProcess = &H80
       SetQuota = &H100
       SetInformation = &H200
       QueryInformation = &H400
       QueryLimitedInformation = &H1000
       Synchronize = &H100000
   End Enum
```

Comment: Why don't you try to get the process id from the handle and then check? Idk about comparing process handles since you can't share them.

Comment: @SomeNickName thanks for comment, but I've tried to retrieve the PID from the handle of `hProcess` paratemer of `TerminateProcess` using `GetWindowThreadProcessId` function and I always get a **Zero** (null) PID. I really think the handle contained in `hProcess` needs an special kind of treatment that we are missing.

Comment: Same thing commented above happens when P/Invoking `GetProcessId`, it returns always **Zero** .

Comment: Then the handle is invalid, i'm sorry idk much about hooking and never used that library, hopefully someone will help you ;)

Comment: What does GetLastError return in case GetProcessId returned 0? Maybe the handle does not have the PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION access right? In that case you might try to `DuplicateHandle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is assuming that there is only one handle per process. This is not right. There is one process ID per process. But every time someone requests a handle for a process, for example with `OpenProcess(..., ..., procid)` he gets a new process handle (which also depends on the desired access).

So you cannot compare the handles, you should check the module name or the process id.

Comment: Thanks, I understood, but please see the comment I wrote below my question, the handle seems not to be pointing on any PID (I get a Zero).

Comment: @ElektroStudios That's because it's not *your* handle, it's the other process' handle. Handles are personal and can not just be shared. It's like if I say "1 meter to my left", then that refers to something different than when you say "1 meter to my left'. You'd need to know where I am and the direction I am facing. The same thing holds true for handles; if my process has a handle 5 then that only has meaning within my process.